# How to deploy maven web service on cloud?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, maven, tomcat

I have a maven webservice and I want to deploy on the cloud like amazon or any hosting site. What changes are required with my project for this work?

I simply tried to deploy my project on "jelasic.cloud", by copy the project folder==> and compress into zip ==> upload on jelastic  and then deploy but it gives me 404 error.

But when I test to deploy same project in eclipse tomcat it works fine. But how to do on cloud?

this is my simple maven webservice:

```
@Path("myresource")

    public class MyResource {


        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        public String getIt() {
            return "hellow world!";
        }
    }
```

pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.start.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>smsdetails</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>smsdetails</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>smsdetails</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.23.1</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

index.jsp file:

```
<html>
<body>
    <h2>Jersey RESTful Web Application!</h2>
    <p><a href="webapi/myresource">Jersey resource</a>
    <p>Visit <a href="http://jersey.java.net">Project Jersey website</a>
    for more information on Jersey!
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml file:

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.start.project.smsdetails</param-value>

        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

this code is running fine in eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The creation and deployment of the java web-application via [Maven](https://docs.jelastic.com/maven-plugin-jelastic) Plugin in **Jelastic Cloud** is very simple.
Let's perform some simple steps.

### Step 1 - Create your environment

Please login to your dashboard and click the "New Environment".

[image]

In the environment's settings window, please select Java and Tomcat 7 Server, enter a unique name of the environment, for example - "maventest" and specify the number of cloudlets (available resources). Then press "Create".

[image]

Your environment will be created in few minutes.

### Step 2 - Create web application's project via IntelliJ IDEA.

Please, open the development environment IntelliJ IDEA on your machine (the application must be installed) and create a new project via menu "**File** -> **New**". In the window that appears, please, select type of **Project's SDK** (for example: v1.8), check the box "**Create from archetype**" and select "**maven-archetype-webapp:Release**" in the list below.

[image]

Then press "Next" button.

Fill the fields "**GroupID**" and "**ArtifactID**" with the text, for example, "demo-jelastic".

[image]

Next, please specify Maven home directory folder (**Bundled (Maven 3) is recommended**) and mark the checkboxes as in the screenshot below.

[image]

Please save the path to the file **settings.xml**. Later this will come in handy.

Now enter your project's name, specify project's folder and press "Finish".

[image]

Now you need to wait until the project structure will be created. It, usually, takes about five minutes. You can follow the process in the **terminal** window inside IDE. After completion, the project structure will look like this:

[image]

### Step 3 - Edit the file web.xml

Please, open **web.xml** file inside of your project and replace its contents with the text below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee
         http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Be careful, links can be highlighted in red. In this case, please go to "**File** -> **Settings** -> **Languages & Frameworks** -> **Schemas and DTDs**" and add the necessary links to "**Ignored Schemas and DTDs**". Example below:

[image]

### Step 4 - Edit the file settings.xml

Please, open the terminal of your OS and go to the folder "**/home/$username$/.m2**" (the correct path to the folder we saved earlier).
Open the file **settings.xml** (or create one if the file does not exist).
Replace its contents with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>jelastic</id>
      <properties>
        <jelastic.username>[insert your Jelastic user name]</jelastic.username>
        <jelastic.password>[insert your Jelastic password]</jelastic.password>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

Please, specify login and password to your dashboard inside directives "**jelastic.username**" and "**jelastic.password**" and don't forget to save the changes.

### Step 5 - Edit the file pom.xml

Please, return back to the project's structure and select the file pom.xml.
Replace its contents with the following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>demo-jelastic</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-jelastic</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo-jelastic Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
      <finalName>demo-jelastic</finalName>
    </build>
    <pluginRepositories>
      <pluginRepository>
        <id>sonatype-oss-public</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public</url>
        <releases>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
      </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <profiles>
      <profile>
        <id>jelastic</id>
        <build>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>com.jelastic</groupId>
              <artifactId>jelastic-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.7</version>
              <configuration>
                <api_hoster>[INSERT YOUR HOSTER'S API ADRESS]</api_hoster>
                <context>ROOT</context>
                <email>[YOUR EMAIL]</email>
                <environment>[ENVIRONMENT NAME]</environment>
                <password>[PASSWORD]</password>
              </configuration>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <phase>install</phase>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>deploy</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.4</version>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
        </build>
      </profile>
    </profiles>
  </project>
```

Inside "**configuration**" directive please specify the following directives:

"**api_hoster**" - URL to your [hoster's dashboard](https://docs.jelastic.com/jelastic-hoster-info).

"**email**" and "**password**" - credentials, which are used to log into the dashboard.

"**environment**" - the name of the previously created environment (Step 1).

Save the changes (**File** -> **Save all**).

### Step 6 - Deploy your web application in Jelastic Cloud.

On the "Maven Projects" panel, select the profile "**Jelastic**" and "**Install**" in the lifecycle's list.

[image]

Press "Run Maven Build" button and watch for process inside IDE's terminal.
As a result, our simple web application running inside Jelastic Cloud.

[image].